# Please help me with latex tikzpicture 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, asymptote

I want to build a graphs with this formulas

first graphic is (, ) =  ∙  (√^2 + ^2) ∙ −√^2+^2

second graphic is (, ) =  ∙ () ∙ −^2+  ∙ () ∙ −^2

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.